Formalizing the implication $dx/dt = -x \land dy/dt = y \implies dx/x = -dy/y$
As part of a solution to the PDE
$$-xu_x+yu_y = u + 2x,$$
through the method of characteristics, the author writes

$$\frac{dx}{x} + \frac{dy}{y} = 0.$$

Now, I know where such an equation comes from:
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}=-x\right) \land \left(\frac{dy}{dt} = y\right) \implies \frac{dx}{x} = - \frac{dy}{y}$$
where both sides where multiplied by $-dt$ and by the respective variable.
Even though I detest the ambiguous $dx/dt$ notation, these kinds of arguments are standard, and I was wondering if there any definition of $dx$, $dy$, and $dt$ that justifies the step of multiplying by $dt$?
Perhaps through differentials as in Smooth Manifold theory, or with measure theory?

It’s a symbolic tool, that’s all. Don’t use it if you’re uncomfortable with it.

Non-standard analysis provides a rigorous approach, building off of the use of hyperreal numbers, and is consistent with standard calculus by passing through the "shadow" or "standard part" map. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_calculus  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function

There's a host of related questions already on this site. Can you describe why they all don't satisfy you, so that we can avoid answering something you already know?

Been awhile since I've done this but wikipedia says 'These integral curves are called the characteristic curves of the original partial differential equation and are given by the Lagrange–Charpit equations[3]' so $dt$ comes from whatever 'Lagrange–Charpit equations' are right?

The symbolism $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is not at all ambiguous. If you don't like it don't use it. But you will be deprived of a lot of facilities established for centuries of mathematic progress. Non-standard analysis should convince you.
$$-xu_x+yu_y=u+2x$$
The characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u+2x}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{du}{u+2x}$ :
$$xu+2x^2=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is:
$$xu+2x^2=F(xy)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary fonction (to be determined according to boundary condition).
On explicit form :
$$u(x,y)=-2x+\frac{1}{x}F(xy)$$

but what is the meaning of $dx/x$, for example?

$\frac{dx}{x}=d,\ln(x)$.

Yes, and what is the meaning of $d\ln(x)$?

Don't you know the infinitesimal calculus?

I suppose that you will soon ask for What is $dx$? Good question but many times duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048987/what-is-the-meaning-of-dx .
